# replace not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Hide column header text placed in textbox but text doesn't remove when show the column in ie8 itself

```
  $("#hideColumns").html($("#hideColumns").html().replace(selectedItem + "\n", ""));
```

Comment: Please add more code so the issue can be reproduced ([see this page for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), also add a better description of the problem and the expected behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#hideColumns").val($("#hideColumns").val().replace(selectedItem + "\n", ""));